# Transaction handling issue with PHP-MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I've a scenario where I've multiple Select/Update/Select statements finally displaying resultset in my web based app. I am not sure how do I handle this scenario. Below is the code for the same. Can someone suggest how do I acheive this? Currently, its failing somewhere and displays nothing on the web page. No errors even.

```
   <?php 

                    //$ConnectionInfo=dbConnectSolaProdDBServer();

                    if ($ConnectionInfo == false) {
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                        //die("Something didn't go too smoothly! Try refreshing?");
                    }

                    $query1 = $SOLADBCashComponentCheck;

                    $query2 = "UPDATE #tmpInterim
                                SET BMPerformance = (BenchMarkValueOpenBase - BenchMarkValueCloseBase) / BenchMarkValueCloseBase
                                WHERE BenchMarkValueCloseBase IS NOT NULL;";

                    $query3 = "UPDATE #tmpInterim
                                SET MTM = SSMTM * (1 + BMPerformance)
                                       ,NAVPerShare = SSNAV * (1 + BMPerformance) - ((( CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY,SSNAVDate,NAVDate) AS DECIMAL(38,34))) / CAST(360 AS DECIMAL(25,13))) * ((ISNULL(Spread,0.00000000000000) + TER) / 10000) * SSNAV * (1 + BMPerformance));";

                    $query4 = "/* Calculate total shares in issue */
                                UPDATE #tmpInterim
                                SET TotalFundNAV = NAVPerShare * TotalSharesInIssue;";

                    $query5 = "select ETFID, FundName, Currency, OpenDate, NAVDate, SSNAVDate, NAVPerShare, TotalSharesInIssue, TotalFundNAV, MTM, 
                                    ((SSNAV * SSSO) - SSMTM)/SSAUM as 'SS Diff(%)', ((NAVPerShare * TotalSharesInIssue) - MTM)/TotalFundNAV as 'MIMS Diff(%)' 
                                from 
                                    #tmpInterim  
                                where 
                                    ((SSNAV * SSSO) - SSMTM)/SSAUM > 0.000001 or  ((NAVPerShare * TotalSharesInIssue) - MTM)/TotalFundNAV > 0.000001;";


                    /* Begin the transaction. */
                    if ( sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $ConnectionInfo ) === false ) {
                         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
                    }

                    if (($stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($ConnectionInfo,$query1)) == null) {
                        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                    }   
                    if ($stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $ConnectionInfo, $query2)) {
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
                    }

                    if ($stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $ConnectionInfo, $query3)) {
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
                    }

                    if ($stmt4 = sqlsrv_query( $ConnectionInfo, $query4)) {
                        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
                    }

                    if( $stmt1 && $stmt2 && $stmt3 && $stmt4 ) {
                        sqlsrv_commit( $ConnectionInfo );
                        echo "Transaction committed.<br />";

                        if (($result = sqlsrv_query($ConnectionInfo,$query5)) == null) {
                        echo "Died: ";
                            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                        //die("Something didn't go too smoothly! Try refreshing?");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $numRows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
                            do {                            
                                while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
                                {

                                    echo "<tr class='odd gradeX'>
                                                <td>$row[0]</td>
                                                <td>$row[1]</td>
                                                <td>$row[2]</td>
                                                <td>$row[3]</td>
                                                <td>$row[4]</td>
                                                <td>$row[5]</td>
                                                <td>$row[6]</td>
                                                <td>$row[7]</td>
                                                <td>$row[8]</td>
                                                <td>$row[9]</td>
                                                <td>$row[10]</td>
                                            </tr>";
                                }
                            } while (sqlsrv_next_result($result));
                                echo "</tbody>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        sqlsrv_rollback( $ConnectionInfo );
                         echo "Transaction rolled back.<br />";
                    }

                    // Close the connection to MSSQL
                    sqlsrv_close($ConnectionInfo);

                    ?>
```

Comment: Is this half-hearted psuedo code, or do you reasonably expect it to run.  It does not make much sense for someone here to try to debug pseudo code.

Comment: check here if you are getting any errors for each query: `sqlsrv_query( $ConnectionInfo, $query1) or die(sqlsrv_errors())`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the reply. unfortunately can't put the SQL statements. But rest assure that all 5 SQL statements run fine on their on directly into MSSQL management studio. It's just that when I try to implement here on the PHP its failing at some point.

Comment: @pravindot17 no errors in any of the sqlsrv_query() but it seems something wrong when i do if( $stmt1 && $stmt2 && $stmt3 && $stmt4 ){} as always else is executed. Not sure whats happening. Removed if/else and tried to run its giving below error:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S02 [SQLSTATE] => 42S02 [1] => 208 [code] => 208 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#tmpInterim'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#tmpInterim'. ) )

Comment: I am running updates using same connectionInfo object. Has anyone got idea where it might be failing as SQL code runs fine on MSSQL? Also, shows no error on the web page while running it with die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));

Comment: Added actual code which is giving me trouble. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Added actual code which is giving me trouble. @pravindot17

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this issue sorted.

```
$query="BEGIN TRAN;
QUERY1: SELECT INTO #TEMP TABLE;
QUERY2: UPDATE #TEMP TABLE;
QUERY3: UPDATE #TEMP TABLE;
QUERY4: UPDATE #TEMP TABLE;
QUERY5: SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2,...COLUMN11 from #TEMP TABLE.
COMMIT TRAN;";
```

Whole of the above code executed in PHP as below:

```
                    if (($result = sqlsrv_query($ConnectionInfo,$query)) == null) {
                        echo "Died: ";
                            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                        //die("Something didn't go too smoothly! Try refreshing?");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $numRows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
                            do {                            
                                while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
                                {

                                    echo "<tr class='odd gradeX'>
                                                <td>$row[0]</td>
                                                <td>$row[1]</td>
                                                <td>$row[2]</td>
                                                <td>$row[3]</td>
                                                <td>$row[4]</td>
                                                <td>$row[5]</td>
                                                <td>$row[6]</td>
                                                <td>$row[7]</td>
                                                <td>$row[8]</td>
                                                <td>$row[9]</td>
                                                <td>$row[10]</td>
                                                <td>$row[11]</td>
                                            </tr>";
                                }
                            } while (sqlsrv_next_result($result));
                                echo "</tbody>";
                        }
                    // Close the connection to MSSQL
                    sqlsrv_close($ConnectionInfo);

                    ?>
```

Resultset is rendered fine on the webpage.

Thanks all for the input.